# <h1> is smaller than <h2> in firefox and chrome

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome

The latest updated code is here: http://pastebin.com/TJweMgtL

Starting from the left, IE 8, Chrome, Firefox 5.. you can see that only IE8 can display **h1** and **h2** elements correctly.

[image]

What do you guys think? What is causing issue? Did I have any mismatch tags?  Thanks!

---

**EDIT**
H1 and H2 are okay in HTML4. I am guessing that it's a browser issue?

---

### New update

I removed most of the unnecessary codes, and only left what is relevant to the question. Thanks for the helps in advance!

The latest updated code is here: http://pastebin.com/TJweMgtL

Comment: Your line 48 is definitely messed up.  (<h1> tags aren't supposed to nest.)  Other than that, I suspect wonky CSS.

Comment: @llmari Karonen Thanks! My purpose was to test the difference. IE is known for ridiculous non-standard generations.. and compare to Chrome and Firefox, line 48 has no effect. So you think it's the browser's CSS???

Comment: You put H1 inside A? Noooooooo..... `:)` [Here are the rules](http://vidasp.net/HTML-structure-diagram.html) (Disclaimer: those rules are HTML 4 Strict and are superseded by the HTML5 rules. But nevertheless, you don't want to put heading elements inside anchor elements.)

Comment: @Šime Vidas  nice guide! Haha. I saved it. Yes. but like I said before, it was an experiment to test what is going on with the three browsers. IE accepts non-standard inputs, and make line 48 larger, while Chrome and Firefox don't (they just ignore the nested h1.... with warning,...). If I remove the nested h1 from line 48, h1 is still smaller than h2 within the <section></section>, as shown in line 34

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In HTML5, an `<h1>` inside sections nested n levels deep is treated like `<h(n+1)>` instead.  So an `<h1>` inside a single `<section>` is semantically equivalent to an `<h2>` and is rendered as such.  In this context "sections" means any of `<section>`, `<article>`, `<nav>`, or `<aside>`.  Looking at your code, the "test-again (now small)" header is inside an article which is inside a section, so it's the same as an `<h3>`.  Which is smaller than the `<h2>` of course.

Firefox and Chrome implement this part of HTML5.  IE doesn't seem to yet.

See the example at http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#headings-and-sections and the style rules at http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/rendering.html#sections-and-headings

Comment: this is something that books don't cover, I suppose? Thanks! This is very good. :D

Comment: @JohnWong I suspect that most book authors haven't gotten around to reading the HTML5 spec yet.  ;)

Comment: Why are `<h2>`, `<h3>`, etc. not also scaled accordingly? What's the logic behind this?

Comment: @Lucius I _think_ the intent is that if you are using sectioning you'd just use sectioning consistently and always use `<h1>` for section headings instead of mixing sectioning elements and subheading elements...  But that's just my impression; I don't know what the actual reasoning, if any, was.

Answer (score 2):

Validate your html and css for those lists of errors. I just copied the raw code and came up with some pretty goofy stuff.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my code. I missed two ">" forward arrow in the two tags. I revalidated (I use Aptanta, which uses W3C), and the two left over warnings were concerning the DOCTYPE. But still no good.

Comment: I am seeing a more fundamental error using validator.w3.org. "Line 48, Column 44: Element h1 not allowed as child of element a in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)"

Comment: @Joe Nelson Thanks. As I stated before, that was just an experiment to see whether it's a browser fault or not. That is, since IE seems to accept many non-standard input (accepting nested h1, which makes line 48 larger!!). If I remove the nested h1 from line 48, I will still end up with the same situation.

Comment: @JohnWong - Are you updating the paste-bin? I'd help if you make your changes there.

Comment: @Rob  Yes. I updated the code. Just now. removed the unnecessary and kept the relevant part. Went to W3C and did validation, only minor warning.... Thanks! But h1 is still smaller than h2.

Comment: @JohnWong - Since the modern browsers are acting the same, and I would never trust IE to do the right thing, I would assume this has something to do with the fact that heading elements have a different meaning depending on their context. That is, you can have multiple H1s on a page now but they should be in different sectioning elements. Perhaps that is the reasoning for the style differences. I had not noticed it before since I've always styled each one.

Comment: @Rob  nice answer. I guess you are very right, as Boris Zbarsky has also pointed out.... :D Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It's not the rendering of a H1 in a nested section that makes the H2 bigger... it's just that browser manufacturers think/agreed, that beneath web editors, producers and developers  the h2 is commonly treated as the visual more important heading! Nothing about outline rendering here!

See my example here: http://pastebin.com/yJ1vzEjj

For IE8 is NOT doing it, is just showing that these convention just hasnt arrived at Microsoft headquarters yet... again its a BUG, not a FEATURE :-)

Good luck!